# How to draw in c#

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to draw the YinYang symbol on C# windows Form Application. So far, I drew the big outer circle and the two innner circles.

I need help on drawing the curve part that runs down the middle of the circle

Also, how would I fill in the small circle and the other half of the circle to be black.

Also, it is possible to draw this without having to have a button (see code).

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics myGraphics = base.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush mySolidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        myGraphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 50,50, 150, 150);

        Graphics innerCircle = base.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen2 = new Pen(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush mySolidBrush2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        myGraphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 118, 75, 20, 20);

        Graphics innerCircle2 = base.CreateGraphics();
        Pen myPen3 = new Pen(Color.Black);
        SolidBrush mySolidBrush3 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        myGraphics.DrawEllipse(myPen, 118, 150, 20, 20);
    }
```

Comment: Just download a vector graphic of it, and render that one.

Comment: @poke i think the chalange is to write it by functions

Comment: @Sebastian506563 I think the “challenge” disappears if you ask someone else to do it for you…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to draw a curve, geometry of ying and yang is so beautiful that it lets you draw it only using circles.

[image]

Sorry for my paint skills, but I think you know what I mean by this pic. You said

> I drew the big outer circle and the two innner circles.

So use this knowledge again without thinking about curves

Comment: I didn't think about it like think. This is nice!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a method to draw on the panel in c# which not redraw what i've drawn? E.g. when I use refresh() or Invalidate() alway redraw me it, but I need something what not. :(